# Upload multiple file using multer failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I got empty array doing below function after follow the documentation.

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
    router.post('/image', upload.array('photos', 4), function(req, res) {
      var file = req.files;
      console.log('======')
      console.log(file);
      res.end();
    });

<form action="/products/image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" value="upload" multiple>
  <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

But the strange thing is this actually work

```
router.post('/image',upload.single('avatar'), function(req, res) {
  var file = req.files;
  console.log('======')
  console.log(file);
  res.end();
});
```

with single file upload.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Upload.array() required field name and maxCount params. But you have given name of the file is 'file' and you are using middleware upload.array('photos',4). Try in below way it may work

```
  upload.array('file',4)
```

or

```
  upload.any();
```

please refer the doc: https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: where should I specify my attribute for the maxCount in jade?

Comment: You already specified here: router.post('/image', upload.array('photos', 4). you just rename 'photos' as 'file' thats it

Comment: awsome, it's confusing now it's cleared, tq.