# Uploading multiuple images with Node.js using Multer S3/Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

**Overview:** I have figured out how to allow users to upload multiple images to Amazon S3 using Node, Express & MulterS3. My code shows my solution below. All working well. My issue is on my edit route. I want users to be able to edit or delete images. So far the only way I have been able to do this is have the new images completely override the previous filepaths.

This is a big problem because that means a user has to reupload every single image every time they try to edit their post. Not good. I think a solution might be to create an images array instead of having the individual image paths. I would greatly appreciate any advice.

I've seen code like this for creating an array with local storage but I'm not sure how to alter this to work with Amazon S3:

```
if(req.files.length) {
 for(var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
 updatedListing.moreimages.push() // needs to push to Amazon S3 here somehow.
 }
 updatedListing.save();
```

**First I will show my "Listings" Mongoose model:**

```
var listingsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   description: String,
   image: String,
   image2: String,
   image3: String,
   image4: String,
   image5: String,
   author: {
      id:{
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: "User"
      },
       username: String,
       email: String
   }
});
```

**My Code to upload Images to amazon S3:**

```
aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    region: 'us-east-2'
});

var s3 = new aws.S3();

var storage =  multerS3({
            s3: s3,
            bucket: 'mybucket',
            key: function (req, file, cb) {
                var fileExtension = file.originalname.split(".")[1];
                var path = "uploads/" + req.user._id + Date.now() + "." + fileExtension;
                cb(null, path); 
            },
        })
```

**Here the code will find the images and create the new listing. You'll see below how I am hard coding it to check each filepath. I believe a better solution here would be a loop but I am unsure how to update the code.**

```
var upload = multer({storage: storage}).any("image", 5);

router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next){

        upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect('/')
        }


      var filepath = undefined;

      var filepath2 = undefined;

      var filepath3 = undefined;

      var filepath4 = undefined;

      var filepath5 = undefined;

    if(req.files[0]) {
        filepath = req.files[0].key;
    } 

      if(req.files[1]) {
        filepath2 = req.files[1].key;
    } 

     if(req.files[2]) {
        filepath3 = req.files[2].key;
    } 

      if(req.files[3]) {
        filepath4 = req.files[3].key;
    } 

      if(req.files[4]) {
        filepath5 = req.files[4].key;
    } 
    var name = req.body.name;
    var desc = req.body.description;
    var image = filepath;
    var image2 = filepath2;
    var image3 = filepath3;
    var image4 = filepath4;
    var image5 = filepath5;


    var newListings = {name: name, description: description, image: image, image2: image2, image3: image3, image4: image4, image5: image5}

    // Create a new listing and save to DB
    Listings.create(newListings, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
 res.redirect("/listings");
        }
    });
    });
    });
    });
```

**And lastly *part* of the update PUT page. This is where the real issue is. I want the user to be able to upload new images without overriding the old images. However as you'll see below the filepaths are the same on the POST route so it completely overrides the images regardless of how many images are selected.**

```
router.put("/:id", middleware.checkListingsOwnership, function(req, res){


            upload(req,res,function(err) {
            if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/')
            }


          var filepath = undefined;

          var filepath2 = undefined;

          var filepath3 = undefined;

          var filepath4 = undefined;

          var filepath5 = undefined;

        if(req.files[0]) {
            filepath = req.files[0].key;
        } 

          if(req.files[1]) {
            filepath2 = req.files[1].key;
        } 

         if(req.files[2]) {
            filepath3 = req.files[2].key;
        } 

          if(req.files[3]) {
            filepath4 = req.files[3].key;
        } 

          if(req.files[4]) {
            filepath5 = req.files[4].key;
        } 
        var name = req.body.name;
        var desc = req.body.description;
        var image = filepath;
        var image2 = filepath2;
        var image3 = filepath3;
        var image4 = filepath4;
        var image5 = filepath5;
```

Comment: @jarmod I know what an array is. What I don't know is how to get the above code to work as an array. Mainly because I cannot figure out how to upload the images as an array to S3 then retrieve them

Comment: Not sure this is relevant, but from a quick look at the docs (https://github.com/expressjs/multer) it looks like you can use any() or array(fieldname, maxCount). You seem to be using any(fieldname, maxCount). Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603732/upload-multiple-file-using-multer-failed.